# Highcharts not plotting Date string as Category

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to plot JSON Data. The dates are in the string format.

JSON Data:

```
[{"BRENT_SPOT":70.88,"TRADE_DATE":"31-JUL-2009"},{"BRENT_SPOT":73.28,"TRADE_DATE":"03-AUG-2009"},{"BRENT_SPOT":74.31,"TRADE_DATE":"04-AUG-2009"},{"BRENT_SPOT":74.96,"TRADE_DATE":"05-AUG-2009"},{"BRENT_SPOT":74.4,"TRADE_DATE":"06-AUG-2009"},{"BRENT_SPOT":72.84,"TRADE_DATE":"07-AUG-2009"},{"BRENT_SPOT":73.29,"TRADE_DATE":"10-AUG-2009"},{"BRENT_SPOT":72.04,"TRADE_DATE":"11-AUG-2009"}]
```

HighCharts / JQuery Code :

```
<script>
  var chart;
    $(function() {
       var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                zoomType: 'xy',
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Brent Daily Price Curve (FPC as at <cfoutput>#f_date#</cfoutput>)'
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    rotation: 45,
                    step: 3
                },
                type: 'category'
            },
            yAxis: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                title: {
                    text: '$ USD'
                },
                min: 0
            },
            series: []
        };
       $.getJSON("brentpricehc_test.cfm?f_date=<cfoutput>#f_date#</cfoutput>", {}, function(jsonResult) {

        var BrentUSDPrice = {
                            name: "Brent Spot (USD)",
                            type: "line",
                            data: [],
                            marker: {
                                       radius: 2
                                    }
                    };

            $(jsonResult).each(function(index) {
                            BrentUSDPrice.data.push([this.TRADE_DATE, this.BRENT_SPOT]);
                    });

            /*options.series[0] = BrentUSDPrice;*/
            options.series.push(BrentUSDPrice);
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
       });
  });
  </script>
```

I'm unable to plot any values wrt each of the date strings. I tried converting the JSON dates to datetime instead but still the same issue.

**Few More details** (for testing purposes):
Modifying to the below line plots the graph with the correct "brent_spot" values. This means that the issue lies with the way the "trade_dates" are 'not' plotting.

```
BrentUSDPrice.data.push([index, this.BRENT_SPOT]);
```

Edit 2 : (Using Datetime type to make the code work)

JSON Data (New): Returned as TO_CHAR(TRADE_DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD')

```
[{"BRENT_SPOT":70.88,"TRADE_DATE":"2009\/07\/31"},{"BRENT_SPOT":73.28,"TRADE_DATE":"2009\/08\/03"},{"BRENT_SPOT":74.31,"TRADE_DATE":"2009\/08\/04"},{"BRENT_SPOT":74.96,"TRADE_DATE":"2009\/08\/05"},{"BRENT_SPOT":74.4,"TRADE_DATE":"2009\/08\/06"},{"BRENT_SPOT":72.84,"TRADE_DATE":"2009\/08\/07"},{"BRENT_SPOT":73.29,"TRADE_DATE":"2009\/08\/10"},{"BRENT_SPOT":72.04,"TRADE_DATE":"2009\/08\/11"}]

$(jsonResult).each(function(index) {
                            BrentUSDPrice.data.push([new Date(this.TRADE_DATE), this.BRENT_SPOT]);
                    });
```

Server side language used : Coldfusion

Database : Oracle

Am I doing something silly somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried your code, and it works perfectly fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/1026/

I guess, you need to update to `Highcharts 3.0.10` to get this working.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for making the fiddle for me. Although, your fiddle code is working fine using `3.0.7` version as well but the JSON returned code is still not plotting fine. Firebug etc hasn't been giving me any clues. In any case, I have been able to make the code work using `datetime` type. I will update my question with the modifications done to make the code work.

Comment: You are not using datetime type, but categorized. So: you create date object which has method `toString()`, so it creates dates on xAxis. Instead of `new Date(this.TRADE_DATE)` use: `(new Date(this.TRADE_DATE)).getTime()` **AND** change `xAxis.type` to `datetime` from `category`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did as explained in my Edit 2 (for xAxis datetime type). Its working fine even with `new Date(this.TRADE_DATE)`. Any specific reason to use getTime()?

Comment: Highcharts require timestamps for x-values when using datetime axis. Why use timestamps? Compare these three examples: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/1033/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `type: 'category'` then you need to assign `name:` to the data points. See the `categories` entry at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis

> If categories are present for the xAxis, names are used instead of numbers for that axis. Since Highcharts 3.0, categories can also be extracted by giving each point a name and setting axis type to "category".

So the question is whether you are using Highcharts 3.0 and if you do then it needs to look something like this:

```
data: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    y: 0
}, {
    name: 'Point 2',
    color: '#FF00FF',
    y: 5
}]
```

see: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

Comment: In my case, the series data has been in the example format "data: [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]]" The line BrentUSDPrice.data.push([this.TRADE_DATE, this.BRENT_SPOT]); would have the series data in the above format.   Using Highcharts JS v3.0.7

Comment: @GauravS are you certain that it's in the "data: [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]]" format, because unless I am just totally confused it seems to me that your data would look like this "data: [["31-JUL-2009",70.88, etc]]" which is why it's not plotting?  What does it look like in the DOM when you look at it in Firebug or some such?